# Python CV2 color detection confusion

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, rgb, hsv

Let's say I have the image below and I want to detect the color red. A possible way is to find the lower and upper HSV range and add a mask:

```
mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, low, high)
```

In order to get the `low` and `high` values, here is what I would do:

I would first get the RGB value of a light red pixel, let's say the RGB is `(112, 4, 61)`. I would then convert it to `HSV` using the following calculator: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.html

I would get HSV as H = `328 degrees`, `S = 96%`, `V = 44%`. Let's say the upper limit has `H = 350 degrees`.

[image]

What makes sense to me is the following:

`mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (328//2, int(0.96 * 255), int(0.44 * 255)), (350/2, 255, 255))`

The first divide by 2 since `cv2` stores hue as `0-180`, the second and third are percentages multiplied the max value of saturation and value.

However, this fails to give me the right answer. What I **should** be doing is the following:

`mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (328//2, 96, 44), (350/2, 255, 255))`

I don't understand. If the calculator said the saturation is `96%`, and saturation ranges from `0-255`, why am I putting `96` here? It would make sense to put `95%` of `255`?

Comment: You should make the lower values lower than your rgb to hsv values enough to cover red variations and make the upper values larger than your rgb to hsv values, likewise. Sometimes it is not good to make saturation and brightness 255 as you are now measuring colors close to white and so would get colors in the white tshirt. Bracket by enough to cover variations in red, but not so much as to over bracket and thus include other colors.

Comment: Note also that red hue=0, so it is the same hue as black, gray, white. Thus you may also end up including black, gray or white if your saturation is too low. One way around that is to invert the image, so red becomes cyan. Then threshold on cyan hues.

Comment: Thanks but, that wasn't my question

Comment: My second comment was just an FYI. My first comment was to make your lower values a bit lower.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Python/OpenCV. I measured the HSV values as 226deg,220,85. So in OpenCV that would be 113,220,85. I apply 15 percentage plus or minus on S,V and about 60 on H. I think the tool you used to convert from RGB to HSV was in error or your measurement of RGB values was skewed. Your Hue value seems to be off by 100. You have 328 and I have 226. Perhaps you mistyped when recording.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
image = cv2.imread('redclock.jpg')

# Convert to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Define lower and uppper limits
# +-15% of S and V, +-60 on H
#226,220,85 => 226/2,86%,33% = 113,0.86*255,0.33*255
lower = np.array([(113-60), int((0.86-0.15)*255), int((0.33-0.15)*255)])
upper = np.array([(113+60), int((0.86+0.14)*255), int((0.33+0.15)*255)])

# Create mask to only select white
thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('redclock_thresh.jpg', thresh)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]